# Reading a very small p-value in R

Tags: r, p-value

I am using R and I was encountering problem to calculate p-value for a large z-score for some genes. I used Rmpfr package to make it work using the following code (thanks to this forum)

```
2*Rmpfr::pnorm(mpfr(abs(38.77589104), precBits=100), lower.tail=FALSE, log.p = FALSE)
6.5625457492544973317295147124225e-329
```

I enter the above value as 6.56E-329. Now, the problem is when I am trying to read the file containing all p-values, it again reads the above value as 0.

```
pval <- file$pvalue
pval[1]
[1] 0
pval[1] <- 6.56E-329
pval[1]
[1] 0
```

I need the exact value for further downstream analysis. Is there a way to read the value as it is in a file?

Much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Most likely, a number that small cannot be precisely stored. On my machine `.Machine$double.xmin` gives 2.225074e-308. Anyway: since this is a p-value, such a small value is meaningless. You should consider it to be zero.

Comment: Thanks for the comment neilfws. I understand this. But the problem is such small values are common in our field and my downstream analysis requires exact value for further processing :( so I was thinking if there would be a way

Comment: Yes, I know that very small p-values are routinely reported by statistical tests for bioinformatics data. That doesn't mean they are useful, or should be used simply "as is".

Answer (score 2):

How did you create the file of p-values? Unless you used `save()` and `load()` you strippd the precision when you saved them:

```
library(Rmpfr)
pval <- 2*Rmpfr::pnorm(mpfr(abs(38.77589104), precBits=100), lower.tail=FALSE, log.p = FALSE)
pval
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
# [1] 6.5625457492544973317295147124225e-329
save(pval, file="Test.RData")
rm(pval)
pval
# Error: object 'pval' not found
load("Test.RData")
pval
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
# [1] 6.5625457492544973317295147124225e-329
```

You can import extended precision values as character strings and `mpfr` will convert them:

```
example <- c("1.4142135623730951454746218587388", "1.7320508075688771931766041234368", 
"2.2360679774997898050514777423814", "2.6457513110645907161710965738166", 
"3.3166247903553998099823729717173")
mpfr(example)
# 5 'mpfr' numbers of precision  107   bits 
# [1] 1.414213562373095145474621858738804 1.732050807568877193176604123436797 2.236067977499789805051477742381394
# [4] 2.645751311064590716171096573816588 3.316624790355399809982372971717293
mpfr(example)^2
# 5 'mpfr' numbers of precision  107   bits 
# [1] 2.000000000000000273432346306476854 2.999999999999999652374485391952952 5.000000000000000485863154281767975
# [4] 7.000000000000000664980387281581168 10.99999999999999974042396434698263
```

Comment: The files are in csv format, which are an output from another software. I manually calculated p-values for the genes whose p-values are 0 and added them back in csv/excel file. Now I am trying to read csv file through R and do further analysis with p-values.

Comment: You might try contacting the package maintainer `maintainer("Rmpfr")`, but it appears that if you convert the values to character strings, they are converted automatically (see revised answer above).

Comment: Thankyou dcarlson for the reply. Yes I used Rmpfr package to get p-values, converted those p-value to log and used that log values (as numeric) for further analysis within my code. Did not save the values in excel. So I got my job done!