# How to get a scientific p-value using the cmprsk package?

Tags: r

Hi stackoverflow community,

I am a recent R starter and today I tried several hours to figure out how to get a scientific p-value (e.g. 3*e-1) from a competing risk analysis using the cmprsk package.

I used:

```
sumary_J1<-crr(ftime, fstatus, cov1,  failcode=2)
summary(sumary_J1)
```

And got

```
Call:
crr(ftime = ftime, fstatus = fstatus, cov1 = cov1, failcode = 2)

         coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z p-value
group1  0.373      1.45  0.02684 13.90    0.00
age     0.122      1.13  0.00384 31.65    0.00
sex     0.604      1.83  0.04371 13.83    0.00
bmi     0.012      1.01  0.00611  1.96    0.05

        exp(coef) exp(-coef) 2.5% 97.5%
group1       1.45      0.689 1.38  1.53
age          1.13      0.886 1.12  1.14
sex          1.83      0.546 1.68  1.99
bmi          1.01      0.988 1.00  1.02

Num. cases = 470690 (1900 cases omitted due to missing values)
Pseudo Log-likelihood = -28721 
Pseudo likelihood ratio test = 2229  on 4 df,
```

**I can see the p-value column,but I only get two decimal places. I would like to see as many decimal places as possible or print those p-values in the format e.g. 3.0*e-3.**
I tried all of those, but nothing worked so far:

```
summary(sumary_J1, digits=max(options()$digits - 5,10))
print.crr(sumary_J1,  digits = 20)
print.crr(sumary_J1, digits = 3, scipen = -2)
print.crr(sumary_J1, format = "e", digits = 3)
```

Maybe someone is able to help me! Thanks!

Best,
Carolin

Comment: You might start by defining the term "scientific p-value".

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was looking for a scientific p-value as 3.0*e-2 or something similar. At the moment the function just gives me .00 which is not enough.

Comment: The output of `summary(summary_J1)` shows a p-value column. Are these what you are look for? Do you want to know how to extract these to use them for further analysis?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would like to see more decimal places of those p-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of digits=2 limits the number of digits to the right of the decimal point when used as an argument to a `.summary` value. The digits parameter does affect how results are displayed for `summary.crr`.

```
summary(z, digits=3)  # using first example in `?cmprsk::crr`
#----------------------
#Competing Risks Regression

Call:
crr(ftime = ftime, fstatus = fstatus, cov1 = cov)

      coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z p-value
x1  0.2668     1.306    0.421  0.633   0.526
x2 -0.0557     0.946    0.381 -0.146   0.884
x3  0.2805     1.324    0.381  0.736   0.462

   exp(coef) exp(-coef)  2.5% 97.5%
x1     1.306      0.766 0.572  2.98
x2     0.946      1.057 0.448  2.00
x3     1.324      0.755 0.627  2.79

Num. cases = 200
Pseudo Log-likelihood = -320 
Pseudo likelihood ratio test = 1.02  on 3 df,
```

You can use formatC to control format:

```
formatC( summary(z, digits=5)$coef , format="e")
#------------>
   coef          exp(coef)    se(coef)     z             p-value     
x1 "2.6676e-01"  "1.3057e+00" "4.2115e-01" "6.3340e-01"  "5.2647e-01"
x2 "-5.5684e-02" "9.4584e-01" "3.8124e-01" "-1.4606e-01" "8.8387e-01"
x3 "2.8049e-01"  "1.3238e+00" "3.8098e-01" "7.3622e-01"  "4.6159e-01"
```

You also might search on `[r] very small p-value`

Here's the first of over 100 hits on that topic, which despite not very much attention, still has very useful information and coding examples: [Reading a very small p-value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334580/reading-a-very-small-p-value-in-r)

Comment: Hi IRFTM, thanks for your answer. I just tried to get more decimal places than those two. The p-value of group1 is expected to be smaller than 1.0*e-55 and I just wanted to know the real value of it.

Comment: See my comment to a similar comment elsewhere on this page. You might find the formatC function useful. I'll post some code. There is real question about whether such small p-values can be meaningfully compared.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the function that prints the output of `crr()` (`cmprsk::print.crr`) you can see what is done to create the p-values displayed in the summary. The code below is taken from that function.

```
x <- sumary_J1

v <- sqrt(diag(x$var))
signif(v, 4) # Gives you the one-sided p-values.
v <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(x$coef)/v))
signif(v, 4) # Gibes you the two-sided p-values.
```

Comment: ```
group1    age     sex     bmi 
   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.05 ````This is my result of your code

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You can adjust the second argument in the `signif()` command to change the number of decimals to be returned. (Changed it to `4` in both `signif()` calls in my answer.)

Comment: Hi Till, thank you for your help so far. The expected p-value is smaller than 1.0*e-55, so also 4 decimal places do not solve the initial problem. I tried 56 and this did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Do you get an error? It is highly unusual that you need to know the exact p-value. Usually it just needs to be below a certain threshold, like `0.001`. I am aware that some research areas require much lower values, but is 56 decimals really necessary?

Comment: Hi Till, thank you very much for your reply. When I tried 56 decimals, it just gives me ten. I think ten is the maximum. Unfortunately, I am required to give the exact p-value and not a threshold. But I really appreciate your help so far!

Comment: @CarolinV R does not use a numeric format that allows 55 decimal digits. The double numeric type has 53 bits of precision in the abscissa.  In practice people generally assume that no more than 16 decimals places can be relied upon. You might be able to get 20 decimal places of digits but the last 4 would probably be arbitrary. I'm lthink you may be confusing the abscissa and the mantissa of numeric values.